# How can I allow duplicate definitions in modules in Racket?

Tags: racket, definition, identifier

I want to basically allow programs to redefine identifiers and when any other statement uses the identifier, it'll be bound to the latest one.

For example, I'd want something like this:

```
#lang racket
(define x 3)
(write x)
(define x 5)
(write x)
```

to output `35`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a hard question to answer, since you might have a number of different reasons for wanting this.

1) you want to be able to change what a binding is bound to.

In this case, perhaps you'd be happy with `set!`. e.g.:

```
#lang racket
(define x 3)
(write x)
(set! x 5)
(write x)
```

2) You want to run code across multiple scheme implementations.

In this case, use something like `#lang r5rs`.

3) You find `define` aesthetically more pleasing than `set!`

Here the answer is more complicated: Racket is a programmable programming language, and you can easily make your own version of Racket that has the semantics you want. However, Racket is deliberately designed *not* to have this semantics, because reading code written in this style is difficult; in a large file and a language that allows multiple definitions, a reader may easily find the wrong definition, and assume that it's the only one.

Does this help?

Comment: I guess it might help to understand what my reasoning for doing this is. I'm trying to convert OCaml programs into Racket, and since this behavior is valid in OCaml, a quick way of doing this in Racket as well would be useful. That being said, I'm not too familiar with how to program user syntax rules, macros, etc. in Racket. Would something like bounding a keyword to "use define if identifier is unbound, otherwise, use set!" be possible in Racket?

Comment: @podington Try the solution in this recent thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/racket-users/vMvHN-OMv7A

Comment: Actually, this becomes an issue when I want to modify pre-existing constructs, such as ==. It seems set! does not allow you to do that, while define does.

Comment: @podington Being able to `set!` identifiers from other modules would be pretty evil, since it would adjust the behavior of other modules. It sounds like you don’t actually want to modify those, though, just shadow them. Might [`define*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/compatibility-package.html#%28form._%28%28lib._compatibility%2Fpackage..rkt%29._define%2A%29%29) paired with [`package-begin`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/compatibility-package.html#%28form._%28%28lib._compatibility%2Fpackage..rkt%29._package-begin%29%29) address your needs?

Comment: @podington You can use `(require (rename-in ...))` to import `==` as, say, `original-==` and then define your own `==`.

Comment: @Alexis King I'm not too worried about proper encapsulation, since my application is for programs that are largely standalone. That method leaves out some other define syntaxes that I need, such as match-define.

Comment: @soegaard Is there maybe a simpler way to handle that case, in which I don't have to worry about handling the functions case-by-case? I was wondering if maybe there's a way to limit the scope of the binding checks to the current module itself. In other words, I'd like it if I can just use "define == ..." if there is no other binding in the module/file rather than all the module-required identifiers.